# Error creating Acceleo plugin: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, acceleo

I am trying to create an Acceleo plugin from existing projects and always get back this error message:

```
'Export Plug-ins' has encountered a problem.
/media/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Workspace.Acceleo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86.xml:88: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Workspace.Acceleo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Workspace.Acceleo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Workspace.Acceleo/org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample/build.xml:315: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Workspace.Acceleo/org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample/build.xml:422: Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

This `build.xml` file seems to be created on the fly, when Acceleo is trying to generate the plugin. When it fails the file is deleted, so I can't check what may be wrong.

I have this same error with any Acceleo project, even newly created projects. I'm using Acceleo 3.3.0 on Eclipse Indigo. Thanks.

**Update I**: I get this exact same error if I try to create the plugin through an [Acceleo UI project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started#Creating_a_UI_launcher).

**Update II**: This issue is back with Acceleo 3.5.1, but this time installing available updates is not solving it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you weren't holding your breath waiting for an answer.  I just ran into this, from xtext, rather than Acceleo.  If you watch the directory where the build.xml is created (and quickly deleted), you may be able to capture a copy, as I did.  But the problem is in the log you have:

> Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration

Googling for this, you'll come to the conclusion that **you need to install some part or parts of the Eclipse PDE (Plug-in Development Environment)**.  Because your eclipse deployment could be in any of a near-infinite set of states, that's about all I can say!  In my case, I just installed the whole PDE, from the Kepler update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/). You might snoop around in your installed plugins to see if you already have some installed components (org.eclipse.pde.*), in which case I think you will want to try to download a version that's at or slightly above that version.  In my case, I had some 3.8.1 installed, and I installed the entire 3.9.1 PDE.  As always, if you have a lot invested in your current Eclipse package, consider backing it up first.

I'm new in this, and only have limited experience to advise from!

Comment: Hi Ed, I am not marking your answer as accepted because I am not sure simply reinstalling is a fix. In my case Acceleo started working again after an upgrade to other plugins (Papyrus in this case); I did not file an answer here because it is such an awkward fix. In any event, what you write about Eclipse ending up in some sort of inconsistent state is probably the right diagnosis.

Comment: I'm sure what I did is a fix in only some cases.  But to be clear: I didn't say anything about REinstalling anything; in my case, I believe that needed components of the PDE were simply missing, period.  I did not start with the PDE package; most of the PDE components that were installed were included by way of Xtext.

Comment: With Acceleo 3.5.1 I had to re-install the PDE altogether. In any case this plug-in seems to be the root of the problem.